# Getting gradle error with OneSignal in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to incorporate OneSignal in my Android project. Getting following gradle error which saying Support libraries must have same version.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Gradle giving error on **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'** and **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide onesignal_app_id and onesignal_google_project_number values in your Android Manifest.

```
Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_app_id> is provided.

Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_google_project_number> is provided.
```

These are the actual reasons for the build failure. Not the libraries/dependencies that you have mentioned

Comment: Yes, you are correct @Arun. They have not explicitly told that.

Comment: Yeah, quite weird :). Anyway glad I could help

Comment: How is this should be done? https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/639#issuecomment-494756894